# Create a list within a list having the data readed into MYSQL

Tags: c#, list, generics

I want to create a list within a list having the data readed into MYSQL...
I'm close but it seems that it works not properly...

When I `MessageBox.Show(list_line[0][3].ToString());` 
it gives me System.IndexOutOfRangeException but technically, what i want and think have done is :

```
list_DB[  [list_line1] , [List_line2] , [list_line3] , ... ]
```

and list_line looks like `[1, 22/02/2017 13:48:01, 50.0000, 004.0000]`

Here's my function...

```
    private List<string> list_line = new List<string>();
    private List<List<string>> list_DB = new List<List<string>>();
    private void BoatGPS_INTO_LIST()
    {
        SqlDataReader reader;
        string query = "select boat_id, boatGPS_DateTime, boatGPS_lat, boatGPS_lon from BoatGPS";

        using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\DB\\STS.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30"))
        {
            sql.Open();
            using (reader = new SqlCommand(query, sql).ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Object[] line = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
                        reader.GetValues(line);                            
                        foreach (var item in line)
                        {
                            list_line.Add(item.ToString());
                        }
                        list_DB.Add(list_line);
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(list_line[0][3].ToString());
            sql.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well when I print:
\n
MessageBox.Show(list_DB[0][1].ToString());

MessageBox.Show(list_DB[1][1].ToString());

MessageBox.Show(list_DB[2][1].ToString());

Comment: Can you explain why a DataTable doesn't work for you?

Comment: ... Heu... actually it dosn't work yet... Ahahah
Well when I print:
MessageBox.Show(list_DB[0][1].ToString());
MessageBox.Show(list_DB[1][1].ToString());

list_DB[ [list_line] , [List_line] , [list_line] , ... ]
and all the [List_line] are the same :( 
MessageBox.Show(list_DB[2][1].ToString());
I got the same answord so for now i have

Comment: I thought that List == DataTable but the name... going to read doc! Thx for the tip... maybe it's a better  way

Comment: _DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.Load(reader); MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][3].ToString());_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list_DB` is of type `List<List<string>>`. Try:

```
MessageBox.Show(list_DB[0][3].ToString());
```

**EDIT:**
Concerning how to fill the list `list_DB`, try:

```
while (reader.Read())
{   
   List<string> list_line = new List<string>();                          
   list_line.Add(reader[0].ToString());
   list_line.Add(reader[1].ToString());
   list_line.Add(reader[2].ToString());
   list_line.Add(reader[3].ToString());

   list_DB.Add(list_line);
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply... I correct it in the comments... But I have still a problem because i got the same answord like i make this list:  list_DB[ [list_line] , [List_line] , [list_line] , ... ]    with the same value in each list_line

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It works! and it is a lot easier code... Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
MessageBox.Show(list_line[0][3].ToString());
```

is  trying to access the fist item (string) in list_line object  (`List<string>`) and then `character` with index 3 inside that string, which will throw exception if string is shorter than 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating things. No need of such structure.
There is a specific class to represent the in memory the result of your SELECT query and it is the DataTable class.

```
private DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void BoatGPS_INTO_LIST()
{
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string query = "select boat_id, boatGPS_DateTime, boatGPS_lat, boatGPS_lon from BoatGPS";

    using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\DB\\STS.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30"))
    {
        sql.Open();
        using (reader = new SqlCommand(query, sql).ExecuteReader())
            dt.Load(reader);

        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            // Here the syntax means: First row, fourth column
            MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][3].ToString());
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Table is empty");


    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! I'm looking into your code... @apomene have also posted a great sample!

Comment: If you don't have a very convincing reason to do that work then you are really wasting resources for nothing. Have you looked at all the functionality available once you have a instance of a DataTable? The List<string> is really not meant for this kind of work.